# Solaris pam_ldap Authentication Using sshd-kbdint and Failing

Tags: ssh, ldap, authentication, solaris, pam-ldap

## Problem Overview

Solaris 11 has been configured to use **pam_ldap** to authenticate users against an LDAP v3-compliant directory server. The Solaris host is only configured to use LDAP for authentication; it is not configured to use LDAP as a naming service.

When a valid user attempts to ssh to the Solaris host, the pam_ldap module submits a BIND request to the LDAP server and gets a response of success. However, Solaris still denies the user access.

Problem to solve: How can I complete my PAM configuration to allow users to authenticate to the Solaris host via ssh by using their LDAP identities?

The user is a valid user that exists both on the host (in the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files,) and on LDAP. The account is not locked on LDAP, and the user can properly authentication (BIND) to LDAP:

`$ldapsearch -h <REMOVED> -p 389 -b ou=people,o=som,dc=com -D "uid=testuser,ou=people,o=som,dc=com" -W uid=testuser LDAP Password:`

```
dn: uid=testuser,ou=People,o=som,dc=com
uid: testuser
cn: Test User
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
shadowInactive: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1176
homeDirectory: /home/testuser
gecos: Test User
gidnumber: 501
shadowmax: 91
shadowmin: 7
shadowwarning: 28
userpassword:: <REMOVED>
shadowflag: 22352
shadowlastchange: 16115
```

### Debugging Information

From the LDAP Server, you can see the user successfully authenticated:

```
Search--bindDN: cn=proxyAgent,ou=Profile,o=som,dc=com--client: <REMOVED>:59874--connectionID: 88496--received: 2014-02-17-10:53:02.324-5:00--Success
    base: ou=people,o=som,dc=com
    scope: singleLevel
    derefAliases: derefAlways
    typesOnly: false
    filter: (&(objectclass=SOLARISUSERATTR)(uid=testuser))
    attributes: uid, SolarisUserQualifier, SolarisAttrReserved1, SolarisAttrReserved2, SolarisAttrKeyValue
    numberOfEntriesReturned: 0
    AuditV3--2014-02-17-10:53:02.332-5:00--V3 Bind--bindDN: cn=proxyAgent,ou=Profile,o=som,dc=com--client: <REMOVED>:22262--connectionID: 103359--received:     2014-02-17-10:53:02.332-5:00--Success
    name: cn=proxyAgent,ou=Profile,o=som,dc=com
    authenticationChoice: simple

Search--bindDN: cn=proxyAgent,ou=Profile,o=som,dc=com--client: <REMOVED>:22262--connectionID: 103359--received: 2014-02-17-10:53:02.333-5:00--Success
    base: ou=people,o=som,dc=com
    scope: singleLevel
    derefAliases: derefAlways
    typesOnly: false
    filter: (&(objectclass=POSIXACCOUNT)(uid=testuser))
    numberOfEntriesReturned: 1

**Bind--bindDN: uid=testuser,ou=People,o=som,dc=com--client: <REMOVED>:12241--connectionID: 103360--received: 2014-02-17-10:53:02.335-5:00--Success
    name: uid=testuser,ou=People,o=som,dc=com
    authenticationChoice: simple**

Search--bindDN: cn=proxyAgent,ou=Profile,o=som,dc=com--client: <REMOVED>:59874--connectionID: 88496--received: 2014-02-17-10:53:02.985-5:00--Success
    base: ou=people,o=som,dc=com
    scope: singleLevel
    derefAliases: derefAlways
    typesOnly: false
    filter: (&(objectclass=POSIXACCOUNT)(uidnumber=10011))
    attributes: cn, uid, uidNumber, gidNumber, gecos, description, homeDirectory, loginShell
    numberOfEntriesReturned: 1
```

Logging on the Solaris host client shows that the PAM LDAP module submitted the user's credentials. Yet, while the LDAP server returned a success on the BIND operation, Solaris reports authentication failed. **Note the use of sshd-kbdinit**:

```
 [auth.info] reprocess config line 160: ignoring RhostsRSAAuthentication option value. SSHv1     protocol is no longer supported in the server, please remove the option.
 [auth.info] reprocess config line 167: ignoring RSAAuthentication option value. SSHv1 protocol is no longer supported in the server, please remove the option.
 [auth.notice] Failed none for test user from <REMOVED> port 54650 ssh2
 [auth.debug] ldap pam_sm_authenticate(sshd-kbdint testuser), flags = 1 
 [auth.info] Keyboard-interactive (PAM) userauth failed[9] while authenticating: Authentication failed
 [auth.notice] Failed keyboard-interactive for test user from <REMOVED> port 54650 ssh2
 [auth.info] Connection closed by <REMOVED>
```

## Configuration Details

### Solaris Host Client

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
Protocol 2
Port 22
ListenAddress ::
AllowTcpForwarding no
GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
MaxStartups 30:60:120
Banner /etc/issue
PrintMotd no
KeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 60
SyslogFacility auth
LogLevel info
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
ServerKeyBits 768
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
StrictModes yes
LoginGraceTime 600
MaxAuthTries    3
MaxAuthTriesLog 0
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PAMAuthenticationViaKBDInt yes
PermitRootLogin yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsAuthentication no
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
```

*ldapclient* utilizes an ldapclient profile from the server.

```
$ldapclient list

NS_LDAP_FILE_VERSION= 2.0
NS_LDAP_BINDDN= cn=proxyAgent,ou=Profile,o=som,dc=com
NS_LDAP_BINDPASSWD= <REMOVED>
NS_LDAP_SERVERS= HOST1-IP:389, HOST2-IP:389
NS_LDAP_SEARCH_BASEDN= o=som,dc=com
NS_LDAP_AUTH= simple
NS_LDAP_SERVER_PREF= HOST1:389, HOST2:389
NS_LDAP_PROFILE= default
NS_LDAP_CREDENTIAL_LEVEL= proxy
NS_LDAP_SERVICE_SEARCH_DESC= passwd:ou=people,o=som,dc=com
NS_LDAP_SERVICE_SEARCH_DESC= shadow:ou=people,o=som,dc=com
NS_LDAP_SERVICE_SEARCH_DESC= group:ou=group,o=som,dc=com?sub
NS_LDAP_ATTRIBUTEMAP= group:gidnumber=gidNumber
NS_LDAP_ATTRIBUTEMAP= passwd:gidnumber=gidNumber
NS_LDAP_ATTRIBUTEMAP= passwd:uidnumber=uidNumber
NS_LDAP_ATTRIBUTEMAP= passwd:homedirectory=homeDirectory
NS_LDAP_ATTRIBUTEMAP= passwd:loginshell=loginShell
NS_LDAP_ATTRIBUTEMAP= shadow:userpassword=userPassword
NS_LDAP_OBJECTCLASSMAP= shadow:shadowAccount=posixAccount
NS_LDAP_OBJECTCLASSMAP= passwd:posixAccount=posixaccount
NS_LDAP_OBJECTCLASSMAP= group:posixGroup=posixgroup
NS_LDAP_SERVICE_AUTH_METHOD= pam_ldap:simple
NS_LDAP_ENABLE_SHADOW_UPDATE= TRUE
```

**pam.conf** and **pam.d/*service***

**/etc/pam.conf**
(Only the relevant parts are shown)

```
login   auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
login   auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
login   auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
login   auth binding            pam_unix_auth.so.1 server_policy
login   auth required           pam_ldap.so.1 debug
login   auth required           pam_dial_auth.so.1

other   auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
other   auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
other   auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
other   auth binding            pam_unix_auth.so.1 server_policy
other   auth required           pam_ldap.so.1 debug
```

**/etc/pam.d/login**
(Only the relevant parts are shown)

```
auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
auth binding            pam_unix_auth.so.1 server_policy
auth required           pam_ldap.so.1 debug
auth required           pam_dial_auth.so.1
```

**/etc/pam.d/other**
(Only the relevant parts are shown)

```
auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
auth binding            pam_unix_auth.so.1 server_policy
auth required           pam_ldap.so.1 debug
```

**nsswitch.conf**
(nsswitch.conf was modified by using svccfg, resulting in the following nsswitch.conf file)

```
passwd: files ldap
group:  files ldap
hosts:  files [SUCCESS=return] dns
ipnodes:        files [SUCCESS=return] dns
networks:       files
protocols:      files
rpc:    files
ethers: files
netmasks:       files
bootparams:     files
publickey:      files
netgroup:       files
automount:      files
aliases:        files
services:       files
printers:       user files
project:        files
auth_attr:      files
prof_attr:      files
tnrhtp: files
tnrhdb: files
sudoers:        files
```

### LDAP Server

This host acts as a client to a Tivoli Directory Server v 6.3 (ITDS). Assume all proper schema modifications have been made. (I've added all necessary RFC2307bis, NIS and Solaris schema elements to ITDS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue is with the 'binding' control_type keyword used in the **/etc/pam.conf** and **/etc/pam.d/ *files.

By replacing all instances of 'binding' with 'sufficient' for the pam_unix_auth.so.1 lines in the files, authentication now works. As an example:

```
login   auth binding            pam_unix_auth.so.1 server_policy
login   auth required           pam_ldap.so.1 debug
```

should become

```
login   auth sufficient         pam_unix_auth.so.1 server_policy
login   auth required           pam_ldap.so.1 debug
```

Be sure to do this wherever you want to use LDAP authentication.

Comment: thank you very much, your advice about "sufficient" keyword really works,
some hours ago, following this ...... "did the trick", after several days of test, **NOW** we have LDAP authentication in solaris box to IBM Security Directory server 6.3.1 remains to refine some details. but the principal authentication function is working ... =) XD